# PHP if condition fails inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-statements, control-flow, foreach-loop-container

```
<?php
$key='APS';
$value='A|B|';
if ($key == 'APS'){
    $aps = $key;
    if (!empty($value)){
        if(preg_match("/\|/",$value)){

            $elephant = explode('|',$value);

            foreach ($elephant as $elekey=>$elevalue){
                if($elevalue = 'A'){
                    $elevalue_a=$elevalue;
                    if(isset($aps) && ($aps != '')){
                        if(isset($elevalue_a) && ($elevalue_a != '')){
                            echo $elevalue;
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($elevalue = 'B'){
                    $elevalue_a=$elevalue;
                    if(isset($aps) && ($aps != '')){
                        if(isset($elevalue_a) && ($elevalue_a != '')){
                            echo $elevalue;
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($elevalue = 'C'){
                    $elevalue_a=$elevalue;
                    if(isset($aps) && ($aps != '')){
                        if(isset($elevalue_a) && ($elevalue_a != '')){
                            echo $elevalue;
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($elevalue = 'D'){
                    $elevalue_a=$elevalue;
                    if(isset($aps) && ($aps != '')){
                        if(isset($elevalue_a) && ($elevalue_a != '')){
                            echo $elevalue;
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($elevalue = 'E'){
                    $elevalue_a=$elevalue;
                    if(isset($aps) && ($aps != '')){
                        if(isset($elevalue_a) && ($elevalue_a != '')){
                            echo $elevalue;
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo $singlevalue = $value;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $value='NIL';
    }
}
?>
```

The above code may be lengthy but it's a very simple example, where if you execute you can see the `if` conditions will be failing to escape the loops.

**Why in PHP if condition fails inside a foreach loop?**

Comment: `if($elevalue = 'A')` <- your problem right there ...

Comment: An advice here: nesting `if` statements that way is kinda messy. You can always replace `if ($a) { if ($b) { ... } }` by `if ($a && $b) { ... }`

Comment: jackflash - Thank you for the suggestion. Yes I am aware of...also for the same logic I have to change the control flow to avoid the nesting loops. Thinking for a smart way to do that..where a part of code only posted here..Thanks a lot for remembering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem :** You are using assignment operator inside **`if`** statements

Replace `=` with `==` or `===` (strict check)

```
if($elevalue = 'B'){
```

to

```
if($elevalue == 'B'){  [or] if($elevalue === 'B'){
```